# Create a application to use with UltraVNC SC

Tags: c++, winforms, combobox, visual-c++-2010

I'm trying to create this application on Visual Studio 2010 using Forms with ComboBox

http://pastebin.com/bV7SF3ni

How you can see in this code all forms is fine but i'm don't know how put option in code

I don't have idea how make this , i maked another project using forms to but with button instead comboBox.

http://pastebin.com/rk61drrY

This is working but i want in combobox and i want too when click on option open vnc and close this software.

Comment: https://github.com/zoiobnu/Suporte.git

Comment: Solved , if someone want the code and want to improve here link